# insert new record to mysql, but not all record success. No exception throw out

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I job is maintain a web site which use ASP.NET & Mysql database.

The web site and database deployed in same physical machine.

There is an interesting thing happen these days.

I use C# code mysqlclient lib to write code in my code behind to insert more than 50K records to mysql databse.

I have used transaction.

If I run the code in my local machine to insert to remote mysql server, every thing is fine.

But, after I publish this code to server. 
Just 6827 records have been inserted and the record count is same for each time.
And No exception has been throw out.

Is there anyone know the reason?

Best Regards,

Felix Zhao

my code show as below:

```
        public bool UpdateEGNAL(DataSet ds)
    {
        bool result = true;

        #region Query String

        string sql = @"INSERT INTO eg_named_account_list (Csg_Segment,Stm,L0_Id,L0_Account,Geography,Province,City,City_Id,A_Id,L2_AMID,L2_Account,A_Id_City_Id...@SWD_Effective_Month)";
        #endregion

        using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(Connectionstr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            foreach (DataRow r in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Csg_Segment", r["Csg Segment"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stm", r["Stm"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L0_Id", r["L0 Id"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L0_Account", r["L0 Account"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Geography", r["Geography"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Province", r["Province"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", r["City"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City_Id", r["City Id"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@A_Id", r["A Id"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L2_AMID", r["L2 AMID"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L2_Account", r["L2 Account"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@A_Id_City_Id", r["A Id-City Id"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dta", r["Dta"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L2_Customer_Segment", r["L2 Customer Segment"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Siebel_Row_ID", r["Siebel Row ID"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AM_SubTeam", r["AM SubTeam"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AM_Manager", r["AM Manager"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AM", r["AM"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AM_Email", r["AM Email"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AM_Effective_Month", r["AM Effective Month"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BCS_SubTeam", r["BCS SubTeam"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BCS_Manager", r["BCS Manager"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BCS", r["BCS"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BCS_Email", r["BCS Email"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BCS_Effective_Month", r["BCS Effective Month"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ESS_SubTeam", r["ESS SubTeam"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ESS_Manager", r["ESS Manager"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ESS", r["ESS"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ESS_Email", r["ESS Email"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ESS_Effective_Month", r["ESS Effective Month"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISR_SubTeam", r["ISR SubTeam"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISR_Manager", r["ISR Manager"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISR_Manager_Phone", "");// r["ISR Manager Phone"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISR", r["ISR"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISR_Phone", "");//r["ISR_Phone"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISR_Email", r["ISR Email"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISR_SRID", r["ISR SRID"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISR_Effective_Month", r["ISR Effective Month"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISS_SubTeam", r["ISS SubTeam"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISS_Manager", r["ISS Manager"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISS", r["ISS"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISS_Email", r["ISS Email"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISS_Effective_Month", r["ISS Effective Month"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SWD_SubTeam", r["SWD SubTeam"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SWD_Manager", r["SWD Manager"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SWD", r["SWD"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SWD_Email", r["SWD Email"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SWD_Effective_Month", r["SWD Effective Month"]);
                result &= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: While debuging have you count the recs of datatable and realize that are > 6827 ?

Comment: Is there any error handeling? I cant see it in the code...